# How can I show that $[F:K] \mid n!$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $F$ be splitting field of a polynomial $f\in K[x]$ with $n=deg(f)\geq1$. Show that $[F:K]\leq n!$ and $Aut_{K}(F)$ is embedded in $S_n$. Show that $[F:K]$ divides $n!$.

My attempt:

If we consider $\alpha_1$ root of $f$ and $irr(\alpha_1,K)$ we have that $deg(irr(\alpha_1,K)) \leq n$, hence $[K(\alpha_1):K]\leq n$.

Now, if $\alpha_2$ is root of $f$ then $irr(\alpha_2,K(\alpha_1))$ divides $f$ and therefore $[K(\alpha_1,\alpha_2):K(\alpha_1)]\leq n-1$

By this way we have that can conclude that $[K(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n):K]\leq n!$

The fact that $G=Aut_K(F)$ is embedded in $S_n$ follows from the fact that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgrup of $S_n$.

The only fact that I cannot prove is that $[F:K]\mid n!$. Any hint?

Comment: I assume you mean splitting field. For the inequality and division property, it seems fairly obvious adding roots one after the other and wondering about the "worst case scenario" in terms of degree

Comment: By definition $F/K$ is Galois if $F$ is the splitting field of some separable polynomial $f(x) \in K[x] $.

Comment: But we don't know if the polynomial is separable @ParamanandSingh

Comment: When we are talking of a Galois group of polynomial as a subgroup of $S_n$, it is implicit that the roots are distinct and the polynomial separable. Remember $S_n$ is the group of permutations of $n$ *distinct* symbols. Maybe your textbook has given some assumption like that at the start of chapter or section. The inequality $[F:K] \leq n! $ does not require separability however. But if you need to prove that $[F:K] $ divides $n! $ you will need the polynomial to be separable.

Comment: In the problem as such we do not speak of the Galois group of the polynomial. It only talks about the group of automorphisms of the polynomial (I know that they coincide if the polynomial is separable, but in this case that is not a hypothesis). However, I have a proposition that says:

Comment: Given $F$ a field and $f\in F[x]$ if $G$ is the group of automorphisms of $f$, then $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$ @ParamanandSingh

Comment: In my textbook on Galois theory the link between the automorphism group and the group of permutations $S_n$ is available only when the polynomial is separable. I am not an expert in these topics and probably someone else will help us out.

Comment: If your real question is about divisibility into $n!$ (which by the way is better rendered in $\TeX$ using `\mid` than using `|`) rather than just being less than or equal to $n!$, then why not mention that in the title?

Comment: I have already corrected it. Thanks for the observation.
Do you have any hint on how to prove the divisibility part?@MarcvanLeeuwen

Comment: It follows from [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)).